# how is the formula for solving cubic equation derived directly from sum of roots, product of roots and sum of product of roots taken 2 at a time?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In $ax + b = 0$, let the root be $p$. We know $ p = -b/a$

In $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, let the roots be $p$ and $q$. 
We know,
        $$\frac{-b}{a} = p+q $$ 
          $$\frac{c}{a}  = pq $$
Now, $((p+q)^2 - 4pq)^{1/2} = p-q$ . And then, $((p+q) + (p-q))/2 = p$. Similarly, $((p+q) - (p-q))/2 = q$.

We thus make the quadratic formula, $$x = \frac{-b + (b^2 - 4ac)^{1/2}}{2a}$$ or $$x = \frac{-b - (b^2 - 4ac)^{1/2}}{2a
} . $$

In the same way can any one explain how cubic formula is derived using the, $$p+q+r = -b/a$$ $$ pq+qr+rp = c/a$$ $$pqr = -d/a$$

Comment: Using [Lagrange's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Lagrange.27s_method). Those functions of the roots you describe are called [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $p,q,r$. By the way, your quadratic formula is missing an $a$ at the denominator.